# Excel special formula

Tags: excel

So i may have over complicated this but hope someone can help me from pulling the rest of my hair out.

So i have 2 sheets one has information that is in rows and the other that i am wanting to have the formula return the value in horizontal format.

Sheet 1 has columns Switch/Port/Patch Panel/Vlan
Sheet 2 has rows (no labels) Row 1 is the patch panel number and the row below it is suppose to be for the vlan.

I am wanting to do a forumla under each cell to have it return the vlan that is listed on sheet 1 in this cell based on the patch panel number above it.

that is the best way i can describe it, can someone please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a `VLOOKUP`:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,'Sheet 1'!$C:$D,2,0)
```

The above would go in Sheet 2, cell A2, and you can then fill across for the other columns.

Comment: Lock those references fam

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response. I just tried what you suggested and it did not work. It returns with an #N/A.

=VLOOKUP(Q2,'Switch Port Vlans'!$C:$D,2,FALSE)

this is my formula.

Comment: Is Q2's value definitely in column C of 'Switch Port Vlans'?

Comment: I am wanting Q2 to return what is in D50 into cell Q3.

does it matter the formatting of the cell? Whether its text or number, etc?

Comment: If the value is the same it should pull through, I would maybe check for trailing spaces, etc. Try this anywhere in Sheet 2 as a check: `='Switch Port Vlans'!C50=Q2`

Comment: Yes it comes back as true. I just copied the formula to other cells and some return others do not. Any ideas?